# menu scroll on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone

I have a menu in a div, that's causing me usability issues on a iPhone, but works fine on a iPad and desktop. 
The menu itself has submenus and some of the respective submenus in turn have their own subset of menus. 
The menu covers the whole screen when expanded on a iPhone, and when drilling down in the submenues I cannot scroll down to the bottom most items.
Is there a solution for this? This is my [sample site](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/Index.html). To view this problem, you need to browse the page on a iPhone and expand the menu.

Thanks
Sohail

Comment: The problem is that the header is fixed in the CSS to the top position, so it will not scroll down (but the rest of the page does). You should consider removing the 'position:fixed' if you want the same page to display correctly on smartphones.

Comment: On the iPhone I would prefer at least the menu be fixed, the header doesn't matter.
If I have postion:fixed only for the menu and display:none for rest of the header elements with a media query for the iPhone, will the menu items still scroll?

Comment: I mean both image header and menu, the problem is on "#headerWrapper". If the menu is too big for the iphone screen and it is fixed you could not see it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the fixed position when the screen is too small, so the header also scrolls. Try to add this to the CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){

    #headerWrapper{
        position:relative;
    }

    #content{
        margin-top:0px;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is working out but now the #headerWrapper on the iPhone is not spaning the whole width of the page.

Comment: When I took away the postion:fixed on the iPhone, the menu is working out but now the #headerWrapper on the iPhone is not spanning the whole width of the page.

Comment: @user2371684 that is because of the rule '.gridContainer{...;width: 86.45%;...}', you should also override it to 'width:100%' if you want it to be the whole width of the page.